# Не работают анонимные функции JavaScrtipt

Tags: javascript, анонимная-функция

Пользуюсь денвером. JS в Google Chrome включен.
Это работает:

```js
const check = document.getElementById("check");
    check.onclick = func;
    function func() {alert("Hello World")}
```

```html
<body>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" autocomplete="off">
<button id="check" >Проверка </button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Это тоже:

```js
const name = document.getElementById("name");
name.onkeyup =sandman;
function sandman(event) {
if( event.code === 'Enter' ) func();}
```

Тоже:

```js
    addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 86)
          document.body.style.background = "violet";
      });
    addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 86)
          document.body.style.background = "";
      });
```

alert() и console.log так тоже работают.
А вот

```js
check.onclick = function() {alert("Hello World")}
```

не работает, как и

```js
check.addEventListener ("click", function(){alert("Hello World");})
```

Comment: Если HTML тот же что и в первом примере и элемент `check` есть тем же, то все прекрасно работает, можете здесь же в сниппете попробовать.

Comment: Может проблема в пробеле между названием метода и `(`?